# Resharper - collapse empty tags in all document

Tags: resharper

In Resharper7.1 is there a way to collapse all empty XAML tags?

Just like below when I do an Alt+Enter to show a suggestion on the .. would like to do this for the entire document.

Maybe CodeCleanup?

[image]

EDIT2:
Using code cleanup (Full) does a nice reformat of the code in terms of spacing.  However doesn't touch the potentially collapsable tags.  Tried these options below too:
[image]

Comment: Not sure - but doesn't the "Code cleanup", "Format code" over the full document do that?

Comment: Thanks Lucero - added a screenshot... but couldn't get desired functionality yet.

Comment: Okay, so I guess you need to post a feature request to JetBrains. http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/dashboard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with ReSharper 8, there is a `Collapse empty tags` options under
`Code Editing → Code Cleanup → XAML`:

[image: Code Cleanup]

Once configured on a cleanup profile, invoke code cleanup with it.

Comment: Is there something like that for server side webforms tags as well?